# Postgresql - return column of referenced table that is not primary key

Tags: postgresql

I have tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  internal_id serial,
  other columns...
)

CREATE TABLE listings (
  id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at timestamptz default current_timestamp,
  posted_by text REFERENCES users ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  other columns...
)
```

Using node-postgres, I am inserting a new record into table `listings` and returning the `listings.id`:

```
 pool.query(`INSERT INTO listings(${columns}) VALUES(${args}) \
           RETURNING listings.id`, [...values]);
```

In addition to `listings.id`, who could I also return `users.internal_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a CTE for the insert, and then check the `users` table via SELECT:

```
WITH ins AS
(
INSERT INTO
    listings
    (posted_by, other_columns)
VALUES
    ('just_me', 'and that''s what I post')
RETURNING
    listings.id, posted_by
)
SELECT
    ins.id, users.internal_id
FROM
    ins 
    JOIN users ON users.id = ins.posted_by ;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=aa02774ee1407752e9001409e1662b31)*

Comment: Thanks! For learning.... how was it that `RETURNING posted_by` worked instead of  `RETURNING listings.posted_by`?

Comment: Because returning `posted_by` in the first `CTE`  allowed using it in the `SELECT` to `JOIN` the result with the `users` table.

Answer (score 1):

Because they're sequenced, use a CTE.

```
WITH t1 AS (
  INSERT INTO users
  VALUES ...
  RETURNING user.id
)
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM t1
CROSS JOIN (
  INSERT INTO listings(${columns})
  VALUES (${args})
  RETURNING listings.id
) AS t2;
```